# How to create a list of increasing unique identifiers?

Tags: sql-server, insert, uniqueidentifier

I'm creating a list of Connections objects (names of machines with IP address and IP port), but I'm having an issue with the `Id` field.

Normally this is the way I would work:

```
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (1, 'Connection_1', '1.1.1.1')
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (2, 'Connection_2', '2.2.2.2')
...
```

... but as my `Id` field is not a simple `int`, but a `uniqueidentifier` this doesn't work.

So, I tried with `NEWID()`:

```
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Connection_1', '1.1.1.1')
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (NEWID(), 'Connection_2', '2.2.2.2')
...
```

That worked, but the newly generated IDs were created randomly, so when asking the result, I  did not get "Connection_1" up to "Connection_10", but something like "Connection_3", then "Connection_8", only then "Connection_1", ..., quite messy.

So I tried again, this time using `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`, so I had following SQL "INSERT INTO" queries:

```
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (NEWSEQUENTIALID(), 'Connection_1', '1.1.1.1')
INSERT INTO [CONNECTIONS] ([Id], [Name], [Address]) VALUES (NEWSEQUENTIALID(), 'Connection_2', '2.2.2.2')
...
```

As a result, I got "Commands completed successfully", but my table turns out empty :-(

I don't need my IDs to be sequential, I just want them to be ordered from small to large (as can be expected from an ID, at least that's what I thought).

How can I achieve that? (I'm working with SQL-Server, using SQL Server Management Studio version v18.12).

Comment: Why not adding a timestamp to your table?

Comment: A table isn't ordered at the logical level. You need some column that you can use in your ORDER BY clause. The uniqueidentifier type is not the right tool for this - use some other column/type for that purpose. (And you can only use NEWSEQUENTIALID as a default, not the way you tried - it should have given you an error.)

Comment: @user_0: I can't modify the structure of my table.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi: I can sort on another column (I'll use the "Name" column for this), but I'm just shocked: the normal way to add an ID to a table, is by adding a simple integer, creating values like 1, 2, 3, ..., for which the sorting is obvious, but the `uniqueidentifier` (which should be a "fancy" identifier) is created in such a way that it is not sortable? From a newbie point of view, this does not look very good :-)

Comment: A table is unordered at the logical level. We should never expect a certain order for the rows if we don't use ORDER BY. If anybody is expecting that, we need to educate them about this very important aspect of a relational database, else they will be hurt from such a disbelief, in the end.

Comment: If you were able to modify your table, then you could use the `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` method as a default specification for your `Id` column and then you can `ORDER BY` the `Id` column to receive the data back as you'd expect. But you said you're unable to modify the structure of the table, so this is a self-imposed limitation. Outside of that, like Tibor mentioned, tables aren't **stored** in any particular order (even with an integer `Id` field), data is only returned to the client sorted when using an `ORDER BY` clause. This is true for all modern relational database management systems.

Comment: @J.D.: Aah, now I get the misunderstanding: I know very well that tables are no stored in any particular order, and that an `ORDER BY` clause is needed for seeing table contents in some defined order. My only issue was the `uniqueidentifier` "feature": as you might know, normally an integer `Id` field was used for this purpose, and it was almost obvious to populate this, starting with 0 or 1, and then add 1 in order to get increasing values. I was expecting the `uniqueidentifier` "feature" to do something like this automatically, but this not to be covered by the `uniqueidentifier` "feature".